# React.js Assigning new options to a React-Select menu based on the input of another menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I'm working on what seems to be a rather odd problem and I can't quite figure out how to go about resolving it.

## The Issue:

I'm working on a React.js website and I'm attempting to change the options list of on React-Select element based on the selection of another React-Select element and I'm having difficulty making this work.

The basic idea is this. Say I have two lists of genres for books. One is a list of **non-fiction** genres and the other of **fiction** genres. The two select boxes are **"genre-type-select"** and the other is **"genre-select"**. **The goal is to have the choice option list in genre-select be chosen based on what type of genre type I chose in the genre-type-select.**

## The Code:

I've omitted a large amount of code so that only the relevant material is here.

```
const [nonFictionGenreNamesList, setNonFictionGenreNamesList]=useState([]);
const [fictionGenreNamesList, setFictionGenreNamesList]=useState([]);

const genreSelectRef=useRef(null);
const genreOptions=[{value: "Non-Fiction", label: "Non-Fiction"}, {value: "Fiction", label: "Fiction"}];

const determineGenreSelectContents =(choice)=> {
    if(choice==="Non-Fiction"){
      genreSelectRef.options=[nonFictionGenreNamesList];
    } else {
      genreSelectRef.options=[fictionGenreNamesList];
    }
}

return (
    <label htmlFor="genreTypeSelect">Genre:</label>
        <Select options={genreOptions} defaultValue={genreOptions[0]} id="genre-type-select" className="select-box"
        onChange={(choice)=> determineGenreSelectContents(choice.value)} />

        <Select ref={genreSelectRef} options={nonFictionGenreNamesList} id="genre-select" className="select-box"
        onChange={(choice) => setBookGenreSelection(choice.value)}/>
);
```

The idea that I was on was that whenenver I selected a new genre type in the **"genre-select-select"**, it would then trigger an onChange effect in the **"determineGenreSelectContents"** method that would check the chosen value and then alter the options presented in the **"genre-select"** box accordingly using ref.

## Thoughts:

If there is a better way to do this without having to resort to useRef() then I don't know it. I would prefer to avoid the ref system if at all possible though.

One thing I could do would be to simply remove the first select-box entirely and use a grouped options list. React-select certainly allows for that and it might even be a cleaner solution overall but I was really hoping to have two clearly separated lists that could be chosen at will.

Besides, if nothing else then this is a very interesting question to solve purely for the sake of solving it. During my research, I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70836533/how-to-change-set-the-value-of-select-menu-based-on-another-select-menu-option-u) on Stack Overflow asking something nearly identical but it was never answered nor commented on so I know I'm not the first to have had this issue before.